# Objective C - OCMock and stubbing?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocunit, ocmock, stubbing

Is it possible to have an actual object of a class and only mock a method in that class instead of mocking the whole object?

I want the object to behave 100% the same as the real object except 1 method.

Ex:

```
MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
[[[object stub] andReturn:@"some_string"] getMyString];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's what partial mocks are for.

> **Partial mocks**
>
> *id aMock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:anObject]*
>
> Creates a mock object that can be used in the same way as anObject. When a method that is not stubbed is invoked it will be forwarded to anObject. When a stubbed method is invoked using a reference to anObject, rather than the mock, it will still be handled by the mock.
>
> Note that currently partial mocks cannot be created for instances of toll-free bridged classes, e.g. NSString.

See http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/OCMock/

Answer (score 0):

You can see on documentation:
[10.3 Partial mocks cannot be created for certain special classes](http://ocmock.org/reference/)